# Referencing a table vs. a figure in LyX, format

Tags: tables, floats, cross-referencing, lyx, labels

Currently, when I reference things using labels I have setup LyX simply inserts the table number.  I would like it to insert `Table N` where `N` is the table number.  Similarly, I would like it to insert `Figure N` for figures.  Is this possible or is there no way for LyX to know that my label refers to a figure or table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load the [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package and use `\cref` (or `\Cref` at the beginning of a sentence) instead of `\ref`.

Answer (score 2):

The LyX way to do this would be to set "Format" (defaults to `<reference>`) to `Formatted reference` in the Cross-reference dialog. This uses either the package prettyref (English only) or refstyle depending on your settings in Document > Settings.

See "6.1 Cross-References" in the User Guide for more details.

The nice thing with that is that no ERT is required and the necessary package is loaded automatically.

However, Gonzalo's answer of using the `cleveref` package seems better because it doesn't rely on the name of the reference to determine whether it is a table or a figure where I think prettyref and refstyle do (they want reference names to be prefixed with "fig" or "tab").